# Secure way to display/download files in a Spring MVC project?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nas

I'm creating a project using Spring MVC and I need to display various files (PDF or Excel) that are stored on a shared drive (NAS), but also mapped in a SQL Server Database.

It's a very simple page that will display links - when clicked the browser will display the file (or it can be downloaded).

However, only certain users can see certain files.  My fear is that when a user clicks/hovers on a File link, they will see something like this in the Browser:

http://www.server.com/springtest/testfile.pdf

What's to stop a user from just manually changing the URL in the browser to:

http://www.server.com/springtest/securefile.pdf

And accessing a file that he or she should not be seeing?

What's the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use java streams to allow downloading of files instead of using links. You can start with this: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-file-download-example/

Comment: What you're looking for is authorisation/authentication.